# Runtime/ Automation Error when specific cell not found

Tags: excel, vba

im running a chunky script to extract data from hundreds of spreadsheets and pasting into a single output sheet. Im having trouble with this part of the code, around 5% on the input sheets are missing "Research Data and Findings" as text, as a result when trying to find it, the code fails with an automation error. How can I set it to continue on if the cell is not found?
Bonus points: If the specific text below is not found then it will copy using the below offsets on the existing activecell (ie doesnt update activecell)
Im sure its something simple but my 10 minutes of VBA training is not cutting it.

```
    'Look for Research data and findings
       
    wsData.Cells.Find(What:="Research data and findings*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
    , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      
               
      wsSummary.Range("E" & nr).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value
      wsSummary.Range("F" & nr).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(2).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code. It checks if the string in discussion has been found and does what (I understood) you want:

```
      'Look for Research data and findings
       Dim impCell As Range
       Set impCell = wsData.cells.Find(What:="Research data and findings*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                              xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                                                                , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If Not impCell Is Nothing Then  'if the string has been found:
            wsSummary.Range("E" & nr).Value = impCell.Offset(1).Value
            wsSummary.Range("F" & nr).Value = impCell.Offset(2).Value
      Else                            'if the string has not been found:
            Debug.Print "Not found " & """Research Data And findings * """
            wsSummary.Range("E" & nr).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value
            wsSummary.Range("F" & nr).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(2).Value
      End If
```

It also makes records in `Immediate Window` for the cases of no match. To see `Immediate Window` press `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor)...